# Access Amazon S3 presigned URL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, https

I got the below URL few minutes back from an API call.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/ssfull-prod/screen_83385208.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIZUOAZEHYVOUHS5A&Expires=1470770496&Signature=Bkyvs2O1lImHUKE4Jq3i2qdozug%3D

Unfortunately, I tried to download the image through Java program, and got this exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=https://s3.amazonaws.com/ssfull-prod/screen_83385208.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIZUOAZEHYVOUHS5A&Expires=1470768994&Signature=QOMe8pYcZX9JJ9Gu2sJ%2FN8KxeHE%3D}

I tried opening the URL in chrome, and I got this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>10C98A1A9AB73E8D</RequestId>
<HostId>
3e/HtjZxuyhEdD3vpf5OBDK/0uSesaE0p0lUZcGd78erFwH48KWB4ExRWFp2PYBFpurEI+Ms4q8=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I read somewhere that I could try putting the bucket in front. So, I tried that as well, and it still didn't work.

https://ssfull-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/screen_83385208.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIZUOAZEHYVOUHS5A&Expires=1470770496&Signature=Bkyvs2O1lImHUKE4Jq3i2qdozug%3D

I would like to know why this URL might be not working. Are there any headers or session that should be added to get this URL to work?

**Edit:** Clicking on the link above works. Although pasting the URL into chrome didn't work earlier.

**Edit 2:** This issue is now solved. I'm leaving the question here as it could be useful to others.

Comment: Whoa! If I click the above link it works. I pasted it straight in the Url bar in chrome and it doesn't! Must be something simple that I'm missing.....

Comment: you should edit your question with the new info instead of posting it as a comment. Also you should add a section at the end where you clearly state what the question is.

Comment: I had read the URL from an XML. It looks like the & became &amp;

Comment: I replaced all the &amp; now to test it and it worked in chrome browser. I'll decode the string and try it again. Also, I had printed the XML in the console and copied the URL from there. If I start using JAXB, maybe it would get decoded automatically.